# How to filter documents with a specific field with X nested levels

Tags: mongodb

I will use two documents in a collection called "fooColl" as an example:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    tags: {}
},

{
    _id: 2,
    tags: {
        tagGroup1: {
            tagA: 100,
            tagB: 70
        }
    }
},

{
    _id: 3,
    tags: {
        tagC: 100,
        tagD: 70
    }
},
```

I have several documents with different nested levels on field "tags", like this.

Just to clarify my logic in this specific case:

```
Object 1 has the "tags" field with 0 nested levels
Object 2 has the "tags" field with 2 nested levels
Object 3 has the "tags" field with 1 nested level
```

What I need is to filter only the documents that have tagGroups, but their names (groups) are dynamic, that's why I want to filter by nested levels.

In other words, I need to filter only "tags" with 2 nested levels.

Comment: will there be many groups like `tagGroup1` , `tagGroup2` ..etc?

Comment: You want it to be no more than 2 nested levels or can it be 2 and more nested levels ?

Comment: Yes varman, many groups... When I said they are dynamic, its because they will change very often, so I can´t name them in my filter

Comment: Michael B, we only have these 3 types of structure... Only {}, only tags and groups + tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution allows you to filter **2 or more** nested levels:

```
db.getCollection('fooColl').aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            tags: 1,
            tagsArray: { $objectToArray: '$tags' }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            tagsArray: {
                $elemMatch: {
                    k: { $exists: true },
                    v: { $type: 'object' }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            tagsArray: 0
        }
    }
])
```

---

The [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) will convert the `tags` object, for the object with `_id` 2, it will look like:

```
"tagsArray" : [{
    "k" : "tagGroup1",
    "v" : { "tagA" : 100, "tagB" : 70 }
}]
```

---

The [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) will ensure that **at least one element** from that array match the specified criteria.

Since the object with `_id` 1 doesn't have any elements, it will be filtered.

---

The [`$type`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) query will filter all the documents where `v` is not an object.

The document with `_id` 3 will be filtered since it looks like this:

```
"tagsArray" : [
{ "k" : "tagC", "v" : 100 },
{ "k" : "tagD",  "v" : 70 }]
```

---

However this solution will match documents like:

```
{
    "_id" : 4,
    "tags" : {
        "tagGroup1" : {
            "tagA" : { "value" : 100 },
            "tagB" : { "value" : 70 }
        }
    }
}
```

Or documents like:

```
{
    "_id" : 4,
    "tags" : {
        "tagC": 100,
        "tagGroup1" : {
            "tagA" : 100
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tks Michael !!! Despite of the limitations that you warned, its exactly what I needed.